# Отделяется ли сочетание "вне зависимости" запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Я различаю только два состояния, вне зависимости от их качества: настроенное и ненастроенное.

Отчего перед "вне" ставится запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я различаю только два состояния, **вне зависимости от их качества**: настроенное и ненастроенное.*

Обособляется **присоединительный оборот**, который относится ко всему предложению.

Сравнить: *Я различаю только два состояния, причем **различаю их вне зависимости от их качества..**.*

Если не обособить, то получится некорректное сочетание, не имеющее смысла: ***два состояния вне зависимости от их качества*** (непонятно, что это).

Comment: Без обособления "состояния вне зависимости" воспринимаются буквально?

Comment: Без обособления "вне зависимости от их качества" будет несогласованным определением для оборота "два состояния",  а при обособлении мы  исключаем эту связь.

Comment: То есть при отделении местоимение "их" причисляется к "качествам", а без отделения - не причисляется?

Comment: Немного не так. Здесь глагольное управление следующее: различаю (что?)  два состояния,  различаю (как?) вне зависимости от их качества. Без обособления вторая глагольная связь не просматривается, а кажется, что мы имеем именную связь "два состояния вне зависимости от их качества". Вот эту "неправильную" связь надо исключить, сделав паузу и обозначив ее запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Обособленное приложение. Выделяется либо запятыми, либо скобками.